# Upgrading from ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 produces a repository error

Tags: upgrade, 19.04, repository, 19.10

While trying to update Ubuntu from 19.04 to 19.10, I get the following error message and the upgrade process reverts.

Error message:

> E:Release file for
>   http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan-updates/InRelease is
>   not valid yet (invalid for another 18min 19s). Updates for this
>   repository will not be applied., E:Release file for
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/eoan-security/InRelease is not
>   valid yet (invalid for another 18min 16s). Updates for this repository
>   will not be applied.

Screenshot of the error window:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mwrh.jpg

Comment: Check your system clock; it's out (or your timezone data is set incorrectly).  You'll find your clock is 18min19sec or more out...

Comment: Aaaand yeah that did it. It's working now. I'm using Ubuntu on a laptop that is dual-booting with Win7 and I've noticed that the time is always wrong in either OS by around 4 hours. If I fix it in Win7, it's wrong in Ubuntu, and vice-versa. Something else to figure out I guess...

Comment: Ubuntu (like mac, ios, android or any *nix) uses UTC (internet) time by default, windows by default uses local time (UTC only in accessing the internet). Both can be used to use local OR UTC as standard, but this requires change as they both the clock to be set differently until they're told.  I'd suggest looking up https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime  Once correctly setup (either Ubuntu or windows) to use whatever you have setup in the other OS, the issue is gone...

Comment: Thanks for the time info! The update completed successfully and now Ubuntu is broken. Stuck at the purple boot up screen. Gonna try the advanced boot options to see what's going on.

Comment: Looks like the new kernel doesn't like my old nvidia driver (340.107 8800M GTX (old laptop)) coupled with auto-login... So disabling auto-login after having repaired the initramfs for the new kernel and this should be stable again...